# Does equality in distribution of stochastic fields at each point, imply equality in distribution of integral over the field of both the random fields?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, stochastic-analysis

Let $(D,\mathcal{B}(D),\sigma)$ be some measurable space, where $D\subset R^n$, $\mathcal{B}(D)$ is the borel sigma algebra, and $\sigma$ is the lebesgue measure. Let $T_1,T_2\in L^2(\Omega;L^2(D))$.

Now does $T_1(x)\overset{d}{=}T_2(x)$ (where $\overset{d}{=}$ denotes equality in distribution) for all $x\in D$, imply that
$$\int_D T_1^2d\sigma\overset{d}{=}\int_D T_2^2d\sigma?$$
Intuitively it feels true (and obvious), but i can't find any references or sources, or make an argument to justify it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course (as far as $T_1,T_2\in L^2$).

**Hint**

**Step 1**

You have that for all $B\in \mathcal B(D)$, $$\int_D\boldsymbol 1_{\{T_1\in B\}}\,\mathrm d \sigma =\sigma \{T_1\in B\}=\sigma \{T_2\in B\}=\int_D\boldsymbol 1_{\{T_2\in B\}}\,\mathrm d \sigma .$$

**Step 2**

From that, you can prove that $$\int_D f(T_1)\,\mathrm d \sigma =\int_Df(T_2)\,\mathrm d \sigma $$
for all $f$ measurable and integrable functions as follow :

1. Whenever $f$ is a step function,
2. Whenever $f$ is measurable and positive by approximating $f$ by step functions
3. For measurable function $f$ using the fact that $f=f^+-f^-$ where $f^+=f\vee 0$ and $f^-=-(f\wedge 0)$.